# show decimal places of number in WPF according to user selection

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, string-formatting

I want to display a number of type double in a WPF window. The user should be enabled to select how many decimal places should be displayed.

I want to solve this in the view (XAML) directly without formatting the number in code behind. I try to display the bound number with selected amount of decimal places using ***StringFormat*** and ***MultiBinding***:

MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
    Width="400"  Height="100">

<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="30">

    <TextBlock  Margin="5" >Precision:</TextBlock>
    
    <ComboBox x:Name="cbPrecision" 
                Margin="5" 
                MinWidth="80"
                ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DecimalPlaces}" 
                DisplayMemberPath="Value" 
                SelectedValuePath="Key"/>

    <TextBlock Margin="5" >
        <TextBlock.Text>
            <MultiBinding StringFormat="Number: {0:N{1}}">
                <Binding Path="SomeNumber"/>
                <Binding Path="SelectedValue" ElementName="cbPrecision"/>
            </MultiBinding>
        </TextBlock.Text>
    </TextBlock>

</StackPanel>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows;

namespace WpfApp1
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public Dictionary<int, double> DecimalPlaces { get; } = new() {
            { 0, 1 },
            { 1, 0.1 },
            { 2, 0.01 },
            { 3, 0.001 }
        };

        public double SomeNumber { get; set; } = 123.45678;
    }
}
```

**As result the TextBox is not displayed at all:**

[image]

**Expected result:**

[image]

---

**Observation:**

There must be some problem with the "nested" string formatting

```
<MultiBinding StringFormat="Number: {0:N{1}}">
```

because changing the code line containing the StringFormat to

```
<MultiBinding StringFormat="Number: {0:N4}-DecimalPlaces: {1}">
```

displays the values in the TextBox correctly:

[image]

Comment: Use a MultiBinding Converter instead of StringFormat.

Comment: @Clemens does this mean there is no way using StringFormat? I hoped I could solve it in xaml directly and avoid implementing a converter for such an easy task.

Comment: [Overview: How to format numbers, dates, enums, and other types in .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/formatting-types)

Comment: @Clemens the linked MS website did not provide an answer. That's why I asked here :)
Thanks anyway. I will proceed with the the Multibinding Converter

Comment: It should be clear that there is no *"nested" string formatting*.

Comment: StringFormat formats an input string of the Binding and formats it according to the defined formatting specifier. In case of the MultiBinding the input are the values of the indivudual Binding objects. MultiBinding does not know how to compse a single value from the multiple inputs. That's why you need to implement an IMultiValueConverter - to compose the input. And because the StringFormat is not dynamic you simply use the converter to correctly convert the numeric value. That's why StringFormat is not useful  in your scenario.

Comment: @BionicCode With a valid format string, a MultiBinding is very well able to compose a string of multiple inputs. Just not with an invalid format string like the one tried here.

Comment: @Clemens Yes, you are absolutely right. I was just giving a general explanation. Because ToString is not always returning something useful unless explicitly overridden. But you are correct, in this case it would work. But regarding the dynamic numeric precision, this won't work without a converter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following [Clemens comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76865906/show-decimal-places-of-number-in-wpf-according-to-user-selection/76872523#comment135508040_76865906) I created a converter. Complete solution:

*MainWindow.xaml:*

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
    DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
    Width="400"  Height="100">

<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="30">

    <TextBlock  Margin="5" >Precision:</TextBlock>
    
    <ComboBox x:Name="cbPrecision" 
                Margin="5" 
                MinWidth="80"
                ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DecimalPlaces}" 
                DisplayMemberPath="Value" 
                SelectedValuePath="Key"/>

    <TextBlock Margin="5" >
        <TextBlock.Text>
            <MultiBinding>
                <MultiBinding.Converter>
                    <local:DecimalPlacesConverter />
                </MultiBinding.Converter>
                <Binding Path="SomeNumber"/>
                <Binding Path="SelectedValue" ElementName="cbPrecision"/>
            </MultiBinding>
        </TextBlock.Text>
    </TextBlock> 
</StackPanel>
```

*MainWindow.xaml.cs:*

```cs
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    public Dictionary<int, double> DecimalPlaces { get; } = new() {
        { 0, 1 },
        { 1, 0.1 },
        { 2, 0.01 },
        { 3, 0.001 }
    };
    public double SomeNumber { get; set; } = 123.45678;
}
```

*DecimalPlacesConverter.cs:*

```cs
public class DecimalPlacesConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        try
        {
            return Math.Round((double)values[0], (int)values[1]).ToString("N" + values[1]);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return double.NaN;
        }
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, replace `TextBlock` with `Label`, which has a `ContentStringFormat` property for binding.

Then, define a class that implements the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface.

The specific implementation is as follows:

```csharp
// in Window_Loaded
panel.DataContext = new PanelModel();

class PanelModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public Dictionary<string, double> DecimalPlaces { get; } = new() {
        { "N0", 1 },
        { "N1", 0.1 },
        { "N2", 0.01 },
        { "N3", 0.001 },
        { "N4", 0.0001 }
    };

    string _ContentFormat = "N0";
    double _SomeNumber = 123.45678;

    public string ContentFormat {
        get => _ContentFormat;
        set
        {
            if (value != _ContentFormat)
            {
                _ContentFormat = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(ContentFormat));
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SomeNumber));
            }
        }
    }

    public double SomeNumber
    {
        get => _SomeNumber;
        set
        {
            if (value != _SomeNumber)
            {
                _SomeNumber = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SomeNumber));
            }
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

I tried to bind `comboBox1.SelectedValue` to `ContentStringFormat`, but it doesn't work.

So, I used the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface and triggered the `SomeNumber` *Changed* notification when `ContentFormat` changes.

```xaml
<StackPanel x:Name="panel" Orientation="Horizontal">

    <Label Content="Precision: " />

    <ComboBox x:Name="comboBox1"
                ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DecimalPlaces}"
                DisplayMemberPath="Value"
                SelectedValuePath="Key"
                SelectedValue="{Binding Path=ContentFormat}"
                VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
                Width="120"/>

    <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=SomeNumber, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
             Width="120"
             Margin="15,0"/>

    <Label x:Name="labelSomeNumber"
            Content="{Binding Path=SomeNumber}"
            ContentStringFormat="{Binding Path=ContentFormat}" />

</StackPanel>
```

Comment: Thank you for your proposal, but I tried to find a XAML-only solution. This seems a bit overkill to me. I'd prefer still using TextBox with Converter as suggested by [Clemens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76865906/show-decimal-places-of-number-in-wpf-according-to-user-selection/76872523#comment135508040_76865906)